# apply jquery mobile style to the content of my dynamically created panel

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to create the same panel for several pages of my html/css/js app with jquery mobile using the solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222589/jquery-mobile-do-i-have-to-create-a-new-panel-for-every-page) .
But unfortuantely, it is like for the content of the panel, the jquery mobile style is not aplied....instead of this, it just plain old html.

How can I apply jquery mobile style to the content of the panel? Is there some kind of refresh command for this?

Here is my panel:

```js
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#welcome-page', function(){                
  $('<div>').attr({'id':'mypanel','data-role':'panel','data-position':'right','data-display':'overlay'}).appendTo($(this));
  $('<a>').attr({'href':'mailto:?subject=subject of the email&body=whatever body body','target':'_blank'}).html('Send').appendTo('#mypanel');
  $('<a>').attr({'id':'test-btn','data-role':'button'}).html('Click me').appendTo('#mypanel');
  $('<a>').attr({'href':'#welcome-page','data-inline':'true','data-icon':'delete','data-theme':'c','data-role':'button','data-rel':'close'}).html('Close').appendTo('#mypanel');        
  $.mobile.activePage.find('#mypanel').panel();
  $(document).on('click', '#open-panel', function(){   
    $.mobile.activePage.find('#mypanel').panel("open");       
  });
  //LISTENERS:
  //$("#mypanel").panel("close");
});
```

Here's the page:

```html
<div id="welcome-page" data-role="page">    
    <!--<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
    </div>-->                   
<header data-role="header"> 
</header>
<div id="content" data-role="content">              
</div>
<footer data-role="footer">
</footer>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made an original post so let me show you a different way, instead of using **`pagebeforeshow`** event you can use **`pagebeforecreate`**. It is important because at that point content is still not styled. Any dynamically added content will be automatically styled so you don't need to worry about that.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#welcome-page', function(){                
    $('<div>').attr({'id':'mypanel','data-role':'panel','data-position':'right','data-display':'overlay'}).appendTo($(this));
    $('<a>').attr({'href':'mailto:?subject=subject of the email&body=whatever body body','target':'_blank'}).html('Send').appendTo('#mypanel');
    $('<a>').attr({'id':'test-btn','data-role':'button'}).html('Click me').appendTo('#mypanel');
    $('<a>').attr({'href':'#welcome-page','data-inline':'true','data-icon':'delete','data-theme':'c','data-role':'button','data-rel':'close'}).html('Close').appendTo('#mypanel');        
    $(document).on('click', '#open-panel', function(){   
    $.mobile.activePage.find('#mypanel').panel("open");       
    });
    //LISTENERS:
    //$("#mypanel").panel("close");
});
```

Working example made on a basis of my original answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/pZzrk/60/

Comment: you're a jquery master...thanks! btw you meant `pagebeforecreate` in the text. And I see you removed a line.

Comment: Yes, line was removed because we don't need to manually enhance pane styles. And you are correct about event name. I will change my answer.

Comment: by the way, do you know if I can add a big snippet of content to the panel by doind something like this: `$('#mypanel>').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain">'+
         '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">'+
           '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />'+
           '<label for="radio-choice-1">I am a user</label>'+
         '</fieldset>'+
     '</div>');` ...it doesn't to work directly like that.

Comment: I've got one last problem: where do I put my listeners for this panel? outside this `$(document).on('pagebeforecreate',` ? thanks

Comment: You can do it inside or outside as long as you use delegated binding like this: $(document).on('click', '#open-panel', function(){ Int his example it doesn't matter if element exist or not when we bind an event because we are binding it to document. Try it.

Comment: ok I see....thanks. It was maybe a silly question because `$(document).on('click', '#open-panel',...` was already a listener ;-)

Comment: Hi, it's weird because I have dynamiccally populated my panel with a form and now I am trying to listen to the textarea to enable a button using this: `$(document).on('input propertychange', '#message', function(){ $('#sendbutton').button('enable');
 });` and it doesn't work, I get the error: `Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'`...and this code is into the `$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#welcome-page', function(){` do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Every time you get an error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method <SOMETHING HERE> you first need to call function without parameters then with parameters. Something like this: $('#sendbutton').button().button('enable');

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Ok I see this allows to initialize the button. I just did it but now I have another error:  `TypeError: this.button is undefined
this.button.removeClass( "ui-disabled" ).attr( "aria-disabled", false );`

Comment: Basically button you are trying to this on don't exist. This is a classic error when button methods are executed on an a tag button. Button methods work only on INPUT type="button" or BUTTON element.

Comment: ok thank you again @Gajotres....I think the workaround is ``$('#sendbutton').addClass('ui-disabled');`   and `$('#sendbutton').removeClass('ui-disabled');` on the <a>