# Close menu and load page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using jQuery mobile with Phonegap.
I created a "master page" index.html that load to #content anther html file.
Also I have a sliding menu that I want to use for navigation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Computer World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" /-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script-->
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadPage(page){
        $('#content').load(page);
    }

    $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
        console.log("pageinit");
        loadPage('main.html');
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">

    <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a id="bars-button" data-icon="bars"  class="ui-btn-right" style="margin-top:10px;" href="#navpanel">Menu</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content" data-role="content">

    </div>

    <div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-theme="a" data-display="push" data-position="right">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false">
            <a href="Main.html" data-role="button">Main</a>
            <a href="#navpanel" onclick="loadPage('business.html')" rel="external">Business</a>
            <a href="numbers.html" data-role="button">Numbers</a>
            <a href="money.html" data-role="button">Money</a>
            <a href="people.html" data-role="button">People</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use `<a href="Main.html" data-role="button">Main</a>` it goes to another page
but when I use `<a href="#navpanel" onclick="loadPage('business.html')" rel="external">Business</a>` I got the next exeption:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
a
e.widget._create
(anonymous function)
e.Widget._createWidget
e.widget._createWidget
(anonymous function)
e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
b.extend.each
b.fn.b.each
e.fn.(anonymous function)
e.widget.enhance
(anonymous function)
e.widget.enhanceWithin
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
b.event.dispatch
v.handle
b.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
b.extend.each
b.fn.b.each
b.fn.extend.trigger
e.Widget._trigger
e.Widget._createWidget
e.widget._createWidget
(anonymous function)
e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
b.extend.each
b.fn.b.each
e.fn.(anonymous function)
r
e.mobile.changePage
e.mobile.gradeA.e.extend.initializePage
(anonymous function)
c
p.fireWith
b.extend.ready
```

What I'm trying to do is to load external file content to #content and to close the menu.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `data-rel=external` here if you only want to load file into same page? if you want to load file into content `$(document).on('click', '#id', function () { $('[data-role=content]').load('file.html'); });`

Comment: But this one  <a href="#navpanel" onclick="loadPage('business.html')">Business</a> also throws that exception, and I need to close the menu

Comment: `loadpage` means go to another page? or load content of the page?

Comment: @Omar, loadpage means to load content of the page

Comment: Then use `.load()` with `.on('click')` callback as in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will never work because both actions will kill each other. At one side you are trying to load panel itself:

```
<a href="#navpanel"......
```

**`href`** can't point to itself like this and it should be removed.

Second thing this **`onClick`** event:

```
onclick="loadPage('business.html')"
```

simply can't be used like that. **`loadPage`** just like classic jQuery function load is asynchronous method. Basically change page can't occur before page is fully loaded. That's why callback function needs to be used here.

Not to mention 2 different loading procedures are used. At one point loadPage is used to load another page into the **`DOM`** via ajax and at the other hand **`rel="external"`** is telling **`jQuery Mobile`** to refresh everything and open another page.

Just use normal way of page loading:

```
<a href="business.html">Business</a>
```

or like this:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-theme="a" data-display="push" data-position="right">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false">
        <a href="Main.html" data-role="button">Main</a>
        <a href="business.html">Business</a>
        <a href="numbers.html" data-role="button">Numbers</a>
        <a href="money.html" data-role="button">Money</a>
        <a href="people.html" data-role="button">People</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or there's another option. Another **`HTML`** page can be prefetched. It can be found in an official documentation **[HERE](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html)**.

If you do it like this:

```
<a href="business.html" data-prefetch>Business</a>
```

It will make sure buiness.html is loaded as soon as page **`#home`** is active.

Comment: But in that case I have to create the same template for all pages?

Comment: Why would you do that? Just open the page, send it some parameter and dynamically generate your new content. Final solution is the same. If you want to find out how you can send data between pageas take a look at my blog article: http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/ look for a chapter: Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions

Comment: Very good examples, but I still don't understand if use multiple html files can I create the sliding menu only once? I need in all pages the same sliding menu.

Comment: Aha so you want to have same sliding menu for every active page. Then I have a working answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222589/jquery-mobile-do-i-have-to-create-a-new-panel-for-every-page/15223926#15223926 It is my older answer but still what you need. You can dynamically create your panel and show it into every active page.